# Vue.js export default not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm following the form example and it doesn't work ::
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form

This is my code, inside my simple basic index.html :

```
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>

      <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


  </head>

  <body>
  <template>
    <div>
    <b-form @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset" v-if="show">
      <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup1"
                    label="Email address:"
                    label-for="exampleInput1"
                    description="We'll never share your email with anyone else.">
        <b-form-input id="exampleInput1"
                      type="email"
                      v-model="form.email"
                      required
                      placeholder="Enter email">
        </b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup2"
                    label="Your Name:"
                    label-for="exampleInput2">
        <b-form-input id="exampleInput2"
                      type="text"
                      v-model="form.name"
                      required
                      placeholder="Enter name">
        </b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup3"
                    label="Food:"
                    label-for="exampleInput3">
        <b-form-select id="exampleInput3"
                      :options="foods"
                      required
                      v-model="form.food">
        </b-form-select>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group id="exampleGroup4">
        <b-form-checkbox-group v-model="form.checked" id="exampleChecks">
          <b-form-checkbox value="me">Check me out</b-form-checkbox>
          <b-form-checkbox value="that">Check that out</b-form-checkbox>
        </b-form-checkbox-group>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
      <b-button type="reset" variant="danger">Reset</b-button>
    </b-form>
    </div>
  </template>
  </body>
```

and the js code +1

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        email: '',
        name: '',
        food: null,
        checked: []
      },
      foods: [
        { text: 'Select One', value: null },
        'Carrots', 'Beans', 'Tomatoes', 'Corn'
      ],
      show: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.form));
    },
    onReset (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      /* Reset our form values */
      this.form.email = '';
      this.form.name = '';
      this.form.food = null;
      this.form.checked = [];
      /* Trick to reset/clear native browser form validation state */
      this.show = false;
      this.$nextTick(() => { this.show = true });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It is stricly the same than on the vue bootstrap website and it doesnt work

There is a blank screen, and This is the firefox error :

**SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module**

I can't show my form, there is nothing, just a blank screen, it doesn't work !

Note : i dont wanna to use babel or whatever complex stuff, i simply need my index.html to work

Please help me thank you

Comment: The `export` keyword only works in ES6 module environments, these can either be created using `babel` or when you use `type="module"` in the Chromium browser (not many browsers support these environments)

Comment: Babel ? What is that ? it won't work without it ??

Answer (score 1):

The example you copied verbatim is the contents of a Vue [Single File Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html). Those need either [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org) to be translated to actual JavaScript that the browser can understand.

You can re-write the code avoiding the SFC structure, using `Vue.component()` and pass the template in the `template` property, if you want to obtain a reusable Vue component, but it will be a bit more complex.

Otherwise, if it is only a single page, simply use `new Vue()` and bind to an element selection using the `el` property (see [Declarative Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering) in the guide):

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ...
  }
})
```

and inside your html:

```
<div id="app">
  ...
  ... vue perform rendering and interpolation here ...
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Should be specified on the bootstrap vue website, which is super by the way ! Thank for your help .

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing [**Single-File Components**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) with using Vue in simple HTML files.

To get the latter you could do as shown below.

Basically you have to:

- Remove the `<template>` tag and add an `id` to its inner `div`, such as: `<div id="app">`
- Wrap the object that was being exported in a Vue constructor and add an `el` option to it:

  ```
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
  ```

[JSBin demo here.](http://jsbin.com/kohedomeya/edit?html,js,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
    <b-form @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset" v-if="show">
        <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup1"
                      label="Email address:"
                      label-for="exampleInput1"
                      description="We'll never share your email with anyone else.">
            <b-form-input id="exampleInput1"
                          type="email"
                          v-model="form.email"
                          required
                          placeholder="Enter email">
            </b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
        <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup2"
                      label="Your Name:"
                      label-for="exampleInput2">
            <b-form-input id="exampleInput2"
                          type="text"
                          v-model="form.name"
                          required
                          placeholder="Enter name">
            </b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
        <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup3"
                      label="Food:"
                      label-for="exampleInput3">
            <b-form-select id="exampleInput3"
                           :options="foods"
                           required
                           v-model="form.food">
            </b-form-select>
        </b-form-group>
        <b-form-group id="exampleGroup4">
            <b-form-checkbox-group v-model="form.checked" id="exampleChecks">
                <b-form-checkbox value="me">Check me out</b-form-checkbox>
                <b-form-checkbox value="that">Check that out</b-form-checkbox>
            </b-form-checkbox-group>
        </b-form-group>
        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
        <b-button type="reset" variant="danger">Reset</b-button>
    </b-form>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                form: {
                    email: '',
                    name: '',
                    food: null,
                    checked: []
                },
                foods: [
                    {text: 'Select One', value: null},
                    'Carrots', 'Beans', 'Tomatoes', 'Corn'
                ],
                show: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                alert(JSON.stringify(this.form));
            },
            onReset(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                /* Reset our form values */
                this.form.email = '';
                this.form.name = '';
                this.form.food = null;
                this.form.checked = [];
                /* Trick to reset/clear native browser form validation state */
                this.show = false;
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.show = true
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above uses your code directly in the Vue instance.

If you want to use your form as a component, such as:

```
<div id="app">
  <my-form></my-form>
</div>
```

Follow this [JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/pucofiwiho/1/edit).

Comment: THank you a lot, so i have to try that ! Yes i understand what you mean, thanks a lot, should be specified on the bootstrap vue website ... I never have understood components, in angularjs either, too difficult for me !